# Two ComboBox SelectedIndex on one if

Tags: c#

```
private void cboFrom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 2) 
        Price.Text = "1000"; 
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 3)
        Price.Text = "2000";
}
```

This code should change a `Label`'s `Text`(`Price.Text`) into the value I set in this if statement but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Because the conditions are not satisfied?

Comment: Hey, best way would be just to set a break point at that line, see if it fires once you change index ... look at properties of both combos and you'll find error in no time .... also you sure you didn't switched indexes with values?